# Simple Pass Fail Java program

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Java function based off of the following question:
Write a program called CheckPassFail which prints "PASS" if the int variable "mark" is more than or equal to 50; or prints "FAIL" otherwise. The program shall always print “DONE” before exiting.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class CheckPassFail(){
    int m;
    public void GetGrade(int mark){
        m = mark;
    }
public void GradeCheck(int mark){
    if(mark >= 50){
        system.out.println("Pass");
    }
    else{
        system.out.println("Fail");
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    CheckPassFail grade = new GetGrade(66);
    grade.GradeCheck(66);
}
}
```

I believe my issue has to do with the GetGrade class? I feel as if setting m = mark is unnecessary for this program. Please let me know if you see any other errors. Thank you.

Comment: First off, there shouldn't be parentheses after your class name. Second, `GetGrade()` is a method, not a class, which means you cannot instantiate it. You can only invoke it.

Comment: It is System.out.println() not system.out.println.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This is kind of "gimme teh codez" (or "gimme teh test casez") as written because it's not our responsibility to test your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Critical problems (these are preventing your program from compiling):

1. Your code is missing the closing brace `}` in the `GradeCheck` method.
2. There must not be parenthesis in class declarations, as in `class CheckPassFail {`
3. Java is case-sensitive. You must use `System`, not `system`, as in `System.out.println();`

   Technical explanation: `System` refers to the builtin class [`java.lang.System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html). All `java.lang` classes are automatically available without you needing to import them.
4. `GradeCheck` is a *method*, not a *class*. You cannot create a new instance of it, or use the `new` operator with it, as you did with `new GetGrade(66);`

Non-critical (but nevertheless important) problems:

5. You seem to think that `GetGrade` is a constructor. It is not. That is not how constructors work. That is not how classes work. That is not how Java works.
6. The variable `m` is declared and assigned to, but never used.
7. Your program does not print "DONE" after executing, which was a requirement.
8. All of your imports are unused. You should not import extraneous packages.
9. The class `CheckPassFail` should be public. Most Java classes should be public.
10. Your indentation is inconsistent and makes your code less readable.

Cleaned-up version of your code:

```
public class CheckPassFail {
    public int mark;
    public CheckPassFail(int mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public void checkGrade() {
        if(mark >= 50) {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckPassFail checker = new CheckPassFail(66);
        checker.checkGrade();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- GetGrade is not a class, it's a function. Therefore, it should be called without the 'new' keyword.
- Class declaration syntax is wrong, there shouldn't be any parenthesis.
- Considering what GradeCheck function is doing, GetGrade function is useless (unless you need it somewhere else).
- 'system' should be 'System' (in-built class from java.lang package).
- Class names should start with upper-case letters and function names should start with lower-case letters (standard).

  ```
  class CheckPassFail {
      public void gradeCheck(int mark) {
          if(mark >= 50) {
              System.out.println("Pass");
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("Fail");
          }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          CheckPassFail check = new CheckPassFail();
          check.gradeCheck(66);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I would just avoid creating an object and have gradeCheck be a static function.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CheckPassFail {
    public void gradeCheck(int mark) {
        if(mark >= 50) {
            System.out.println("Pass");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckPassFail grade = new CheckPassFail();
        grade.gradeCheck(66);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CheckPassFail
{
int m;

CheckPassFail(int mark){
    m = mark;
}

public void gradeCheck(int mark){
if(mark >= 50){
System.out.println("Pass");
}
else{
System.out.println("Fail");
}}

public static void main(String[] args) {
CheckPassFail grade = new CheckPassFail(66);
grade.gradeCheck(66);
}}
```